# Win 7 connects via VPN L2TP to Mac Mini 10.9.2 but can't map drive to file share

Tags: windows-7, mac, vpn

I'm connected via VPN L2TP protocol to Mac Mini server running Mavericks 10.9.2, but can't see network or map a drive to the file share. Why not??

Answer (score 0):

Probably the routes on the win 7 that are not set. if you open a terminal and type in `netstat -r`, you should see if there is a route to your internal network through the vpn connection.
If not, you need to set it. Could be that the vpn client isn't configured correctly or is unable to set the route.

command to set the route is : `route -n add -net <your network>/<your subnet> <your ip of the vpn connection>`